# How to get the value out of this type of dictionary in c#

Tags: c#, for-loop, dictionary, key-value

I want to create, because I understand dictionaries are `key=>value` in C#, a dictionary that is much like `key=>value(key=>value)`

Currently I I know I can do:

`Dictionary<int, int> someVar = new Dictionary<int, int>();`

which creates me a key=>value.

To create what I want I could do (this is just a guess, please correct me if I am wrong):

`Dictionary<int Dictionray<int, int>> someVar = new Dictionary<int, Dictionray<int, int>>`

Now comes the fun part, I want to do **ONE** and only **ONE** for loop over this dictponary object **YET** get all values so it would look something like:

```
foreach (KeyValuePair<int, int> pair in someVar){
    //object = base dictionary key
    //object2 = nested dictionary key
    //object3 = nested dictionary value 
}
```

Now I come from PHP so this would be dead easy to do in one for loop. what are your ideas? because I am new to C# and the term dictionary (even though php arrays are dictionaries).

I know in C# with a for loop like this I could do: `pair.Key` and `pair.Value.`

My second part, is **How do I add values to such a dictionary? I know the typical .add(bla, bla) but how do you add values to the nested part?**

Comment: Is there a particular business reason for your data structure needs?  What is the scenario behind this dictionary?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Iterating

In C#, `IDictionary<TKey, TValue>` implements `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>`.  So, you can iterate over an instance of type `IDictionary<TKey, TValue>` using `foreach` or a Linq query, and get every `KeyValuePair` in the data structure.  Since your `TValue` is in this case itself an `IDictionary`, you can do this on the inner structure as well:

```
foreach(var kvp in myDictionary)
{
    foreach(var innerKvp in kvp.Value)
    {
         var myValue = innerKvp.Value
         //Logic on myValue
    }
}
```

Using the Linq library, you can use `SelectMany` to get all of the `KeyValuePair` instances quite elegantly:

```
myDictionary.SelectMany(kvp => kvp.Value);
```

`SelectMany` essentially flattens a list of lists.  This Linq query is saying: for each key value pair in my dictionary, get all the inner dictionaries, treat them as lists of key value pairs, and then flatten all those lists.  This will return an `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>`.

If instead you only care about the values of the inner dictionary, and not the keys, you can use the `Values` property on `IDictionary<TKey, TValue>` which returns an `IEnumerable<TValue>` of all the values in the dictionary.  We can then use `SelectMany` to get a list that contains all the values in the dictionary of dictionaries:

```
myDictionary.Values.SelectMany(dict => dict.Values);
```

Read more about `IDictionary<TKey, TValue>` [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s4ys34ea.aspx) and more about `KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>` [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5tbh8a42.aspx).

### **Adding**

In order to add an element to this data structure, you'll have to first check if the inner dictionaries are null.  Let's say we're trying to add `3` to the dictionary keyed by `2` in the dictionary keyed by `1`:

```
var myInnerDictionary = myDictionary.ContainsKey(1) ? myDictionary[1] : (myDictionary[1] = new Dictionary<int, int>());
myInnerDictionary[1][2] = 3;
```

Of course this will override a value in that location if it already exists, so you might want to check that as well, or use the `Add` method, which will not overwrite.

You should also learn about the `ToDictionary` Linq method which can help you construct dictionaries from other `IEnumerables`.  Read about it [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549277.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

use linq to get all the values

```
var values = someVar.SelectMany(x => x.Values);
```

as for how to add values to the nested part, you'd just need the key for the outer dictionary for which sub dictionary you want to to add it to:

```
someVar[key].Add(0, 0);
```

Comment: Thank you. Can you please explain in more detail in how to get the information I want from the  dictionary? your explanation is a bit vague and as some one who's new I don't understand what you mean. thanks.

Comment: bens answer is more thorough, and should have all the info you need

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible to get all the values including nested by using only one `foreach` loop, unless nested `Dictionaries` have a values which you can get without using loop, like this:

```
foreach (var pair in someVar){
    var object1 = (Dictionary<int,int>)pair.Value;
    var object2 = object1[0].Value;
    var object3 = object1[1].Value; 
    .....

    // To add a values to the nested Dictionary just use Dictionary.Add method:
    object1.Add(1,1);
}
```